# Extracting features from chessboard

Tags: open-source, library, java, chess

So I am implementing an intelligent chess agent with the use of reinforcement learning. I intend to use Java.

After reading the [master thesis of H.Mannen](http://www.phil.uu.nl/preprints/ckiscripties/SCRIPTIES/029_mannen.pdf) I decided to use some of the features listed on Appendix B of his master that can be found on page 67.

Description of the features:

- **Board control**: amount of empty squares controlled by a side
- **Connectivity**: amount of connectedness between the pieces of a side
- **King’s distance to center**: amount of squares a king is separated from
  one of the center squares e4, d4, e5, d5
- **Total mobility**: total sum of squares reachable by a side
- **Center control**: amount of pawns occupying the squares e4, d4, e5,
  d5.
- **Isolated pawns**: amount of pawns without a pawn of its own side on
  an adjacent line.
- **Doubled pawns**: amount of pawns, greater than 1, on 1 line.
- **Passed pawns**: amount of pawns without an enemy pawn ahead of
  it on the same or an adjacent line.
- **Pawn forks**: amount of pawns which attack two superior pieces.

Due to the fact that my project is focused on the AI part of the chess agent I would like to use some preexisting open source Java libraries or functions that automate the proccess of extracting these features from the chessboard.

After searching, the only thing I found was [Chesspresso](http://www.chesspresso.org/) but it comes with no tutorial and I was unable to find one. So I have two questions:

- Do you know any good tutorials for Chesspresso?
- Are aware of any Java open source library that will help me extract the features I want from the chessboard so I can reduce the programming cost of the project?